# Reliability with Neo4J- Is there a way to configure neo4j to not crash?

Tags: neo4j

I am evaluating neo4j for production usage. During my playing around with neo4j it crashed (OutOfMemory exceptions) many times due to non-optimized queries.

I understand that perhaps there's not enough memory. In other databases I've used the server doesn't just crash, but instead slows down or terminates a specific query/transaction. Neo4j on the other hand simply shuts down.

Is there a way to configure neo4j to not crash?

---

##### Here's a response I received from the neo4j team:

> you can configure several options, that we e.g. have also enabled in
> sandbox:
>
> 1. transaction and global memory limits, the global memory limit should be around 70% of the configured heap, and if you know what the
>    concurrency of your statements is you can also configure the
>    per-statement memory limit if you don't have outlier queries
> 2. transaction timeouts, limit queries to at most X seconds runtime and abort them after
>
> Those settings should be default for new installations but
> unfortunately aren't yet.

[Source](https://community.neo4j.com/t/reliability-with-neo4j-is-there-a-way-to-configure-neo4j-to-not-crash/60858)

Comment: Can I ask you how big is the dataset (nodes and relationships)?

Comment: @KWriter the size irrelevant (meaning the cause of the crash is irrelevant). However, it crashed with 10k MERGE operations (which I've addressed). What the question here is how to prevent crashes. These queries can be run in a thread, and shouldn't be crashing the entire server. The question is how to prevent crashes when out of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to control and limit transaction memory usage, see : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/#memory-configuration-limit-transaction-memory